# how can I compare similarity between strings from two tables (one to many) in MySQL table using python

Tags: mysql, pandas, python-2.7, mysql-connector

I have 90K rows in "table1" and 95k rows in "table2". I tried with the below code to compare every rows from table1 to table2. But it takes 1 minute to complete the 1 row from table1 against all rows of table2. Please help me to speed up the process.

```
from thefuzz import fuzz, process

import mysql.connector
from pandas import DataFrame
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    password="",
    database="db_test"
)
cursorObject = mydb.cursor()

query = "SELECT * FROM table1"
cursorObject.execute(query)

myresult = cursorObject.fetchall()
df = DataFrame(myresult)


query1 = "SELECT * from table2"
cursorObject.execute(query1)
myresult1 = cursorObject.fetchall()
df1 = DataFrame(myresult1)

for ind, row in df.iterrows():
    string1= row[1]
    for ind1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
        string2= row1[1]
        similarity=fuzz.ratio(string1, string2)
        print(similarity)
```

Comment: First of all, don't use `SELECT *` if you only care about 1 column.

Comment: i have only one column in both the tables